# http://api.stackoverflow.com is a bit of a maze, can it be changed?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, api

I decided to Google for the StackExchange API. The first link on Google is:

```
http://api.stackoverflow.com
```

This itself transforms into:

```
http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage
```

This has a big notice at the top saying "The V1.x family of APIs is obsolete, having been replaced by the V2.x family", which in turn links to:

```
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchange-api-v2-0-no-longer-beta
```

...which *finally* links to:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com
```

Hoorah!

---

Can http://api.stackoverflow.com instead redirect directly to the V2.0 API?

A link can then be added to the V2.0 API site to point back to the V1.x documentation for anyone still needing to access that.

Comment: Yeah.. I got really confused as well.

Comment: So for v2 we added security?

Comment: @djechlin security by redirection! It's like a giant shell game! Which one is the API under? I don't know!

Comment: If we redirected automatically we'd break any v1 clients.  Not that I'm disagreeing it should be easier to navigate to, it most certainly should since we'd like to get everyone off v1.

Comment: @NickCraver as someone who hasn't used the API (yet), what is the reason redirecting just that page would break V1 clients?

Comment: @Nick: ... even if you just redirect the homepage, rather than the whole domain?

Comment: @Matt then how would you find any documentation on V1? It should be a header and one link away IMO.

Comment: @NickCraver I think you've misunderstood my redirection request. The only part that would need to be redirected is the base URL (`http://api.stackoverflow.com`). The documentation would still exist at `http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage`.

Comment: @James, and they'd find that URL....how? We do still support it, even if we'd like people to move to v2.

Comment: @NickCraver: By adding a link to the v1 documentation on https://api.stackexchange.com/ ? If both http and https go to (what is now) https://api.stackexchange.com/, a link to the v1 documentation on that page lets everyone access the API they're after, without any jumping through hoops and redirects. I'm not against a header & one jump link, #justsaying I don't see the issue of redirecting the homepage.

Comment: @Matt the API documentation links and testing for v1 is *per site*, you can't link to any one place from there, stackoverflow is one of nearly 200 sites with an API v1 endpoint.

Comment: @NickCraver: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh. I've been missing v1 was on each sites domain, rather than SE.com ;). Nowwwww I understand :P.

Comment: @NickCraver ^ "A link can then be added to the V2.0 API site to point back to the V1.x documentation for anyone still needing to access that." Something like http://i.imgur.com/VOaSyam.png **Edit:** Oh, I see.

Comment: @Matt yup, which is why it won't be included in [the SSL move](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/), it's another ~200 domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181206/http-api-stackoverflow-com-is-a-bit-of-a-maze-can-it-be-changed#comment550648_181206) by Nick Craver, he explains why http://api.stackoverflow.com can't redirect directly to https://api.stackexchange.com/:

> If we redirected automatically we'd break any v1 clients. Not that I'm disagreeing it should be easier to navigate to, it most certainly should since we'd like to get everyone off v1. – Nick Craver♦

Therefore, I think the link on http://api.stackoverflow.com should just redirect to https://api.stackexchange.com/. If I click there, I probably want to go to the v2 api, not go to a blog post about the v2 api.

Also, the link is kind of hard to see since it's only four characters:

[image]

I think the link should include the text "the V2.x family," so it is easier to notice. Not only does Fitts' Law apply, [it is also almost impossible to see when you have visited the link already.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wltyw.png)

Comment: It's a very bad assumption that someone visiting v1 automatically wants to redirect to v2.  People supporting v1 apps, or porting to v2 most certainly wants to see the v1 documentation.  We don't want to hide the old documentation, we'd like people to use it to port over.